# how to use results from Api-request without putting them to the state React Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to use results that I got from Api-request use directly in the `render()`. Can I do it?

```
const fetchUsersFromApi = () => fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?_limit=10')

function* fetchUserWorker() {
    const data = yield call(fetchUsersFromApi)
    const json = yield call(() => new Promise(res => res(data.json())))
    yield put(setUsers(json))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do it . Considering you are firing the API call after the component is mounted inside your `useEffect` for function component or `componentDidMount` in case of class component .

You need a state to hold the initial users value . Initially `users` will be an `[]` and once you make the API call your users might be list of users `[{}, {}]`. Now if you see here we are changing the value from `[]` to `[{}, {}]` over a period of time. `State` provided by react is for this purpose . Whenever a value changes over a period of time either by API calls or by user Interactions then it has to be held in `State` .